# Show file's history in Time Machine via Terminal

Tags: terminal, backup, time-machine

I've checked online about Time Machine via Terminal, and I could not find this use case:

Given a file path, show me a list of the file's TM backup version with their dates.

The real use case is to find out when a file was created, as duplicated files retain the creation date of the original. Since I have daily backups, oldest TM entry would reveal the real created date.